# Change the priority of webcams (Windows XP)

Tags: webcam

I have two USB webcams plugged into my computer.  Unfortunately, all the applications I've been testing seem to be defaulting to the wrong one, with no way to change it.

Is there some way to change the 'default' webcam?

Comment: Could you not just unplug one of the webcams?

Comment: I can, and that means they point to the correct one, but if I then plug it back in, they point to the wrong one again...